# Flattening Multi-Level Nested Object to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert an object/dictionary to a Python DataFrame using the following code:

```
sr = pd.Series(object)
df = pd.DataFrame(sr.values.tolist())
display(df)
```

It works well but some of the output columns are of object/dictionary type, and I would like to break them up to multiple columns, for example, if column "Items" produces the following value in a cell:

```
obj = {
    "item1": {
        "id": "item1",
        "relatedItems": [
            {
                "id": "1111",
                "category": "electronics"
            },
            {
                "id": "9999",
                "category": "electronics",
                "subcategory": "computers"
            },
            {
                "id": "2222",
                "category": "electronics",
                "subcategory": "computers",
                "additionalData": {
                    "createdBy": "Doron",
                    "inventory": 100
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "item2": {
        "id": "item2",
        "relatedItems": [
            {
                "id": "4444",
                "category": "furniture",
                "subcategory": "sofas"
            },
            {
                "id": "5555",
                "category": "books",
            },
            {
                "id": "6666",
                "category": "electronics",
                "subcategory": "computers",
                "additionalData": {
                    "createdBy": "Joe",
                    "inventory": 5,
                    "condition": {
                        "name": "new",
                        "inspectedBy": "Doron"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The desired output is:
[image: objResult]

I tried using df.explode, but it multiplies the row to multiple rows, I am looking for a way to achieve the same but split into columns and retain a single row.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at [pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) which has a (`sep`) parameter:​

```
obj = {
        'name': 'Doron Barel',
        'items': {
            'item_name': 'name',
            'item_value': 'value',
            'another_item_prop': [
                {
                'subitem1_name': 'just_another_name',
                'subitem1_value': 'just_another_value',
                },
                {
                'subitem2_name': 'one_more_name',
                'subitem2_value': 'one_more_value',
                }
                                  ]
                                 
                 }
       }
​
df = pd.json_normalize(obj, sep='.')
​
ser = df.pop('items.another_item_prop').explode()
​
out = (df.join(pd.DataFrame(ser.tolist(), index=s.index)
                .rename(columns= lambda x: ser.name+"."+x))
                .groupby("name", as_index=False).first()
            )
```

Output :

```
print(out)
​
          name items.item_name items.item_value items.another_item_prop.subitem1_name items.another_item_prop.subitem1_value items.another_item_prop.subitem2_name items.another_item_prop.subitem2_value
0  Doron Barel            name            value                     just_another_name                     just_another_value                         one_more_name                         one_more_value
```

Comment: If "another_item_prop" is a list of dictionaries, the 'items.another_item_prop' is not split to columns and the value is the original list of dictionaries. Is there any way to cause it to continue normalizing until reaching the very final level of nesting?

Comment: Is it possible to have the output in a single row? currently there are 2.

Comment: Thanks. I see that I have to specify the column containing the list of dictionaries (items.another_item_prop). Ideally I would like a generic function that takes any nested dictionary and splits it into columns. Also, I'd like the columns to be "Name", "items.item_name", "items.item_value", "another_item_prop.0.subitem_name" (0 indicating the current list index), "another_item_prop.0.subitem_value", "another_item_prop.1.subitem_name", "another_item_prop.1.subitem_value"

Comment: I think it's possible but can you share a reproducible example describing the most your real dataset and the matching expected output ?

Comment: I updated the original post with a more representative object and the desired output. Thank you!!

Comment: Timeless any suggestions how to handle this data structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pd.json_normalize function to flatten the nested dictionary into multiple columns, with the keys joined with a dot (.).

```
sr = pd.Series({
'Items': {
    'item_name': 'name',
    'item_value': 'value'
 }
})

df = pd.json_normalize(sr, sep='.')
display(df)
```

This will give you the following df

```
  Items.item_name Items.item_value
   0           name           value
```

You can also specify the level of nesting by passing the record_path parameter to pd.json_normalize, for example, to only flatten the 'Items' key:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(sr, 'Items', sep='.')
display(df)
```

Comment: It worked great but it looks like the normalization is limited to 2 levels only for some reason, in one of the sub columns the values are lists of objects.

Comment: df = pd.json_normalize(sr['Items'], record_path=['item_name', 'item_value'], meta=['item_name', 'item_value'], meta_prefix='Items.')